# Deployd error date must be string

Tags: database, node.js, date, npm, deployd

I got an date column in deployd type of string.

Value etc. 2015-06-24T22:00:00.955Z

But when i i try to update an other column in that row, deployd gives me the error date must be string

I tried to convert the column to number, put then i cant put in the date.

Comment: Why would you make a date column a number? Make it a date type...

Comment: there arnt date types in deployd

Comment: then convert the date to a number, e.g. a unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I haven't found anyting better, than writing to the column value with `new Date().toString()` instead of `new Date()`. With this you won't have to change client side code.